# Run executable right after building (c, cmake, make)

Tags: c, cmake, mingw, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to run my executable right after building it by using a post-build step (add_custom_command).

So far we used a WSL environment on Windows 10, which worked. Now we switch to directly building it in the Windows cmd, which gives us an error...

CMakeLists.txt extract:

```
# Execute unit tests after build and write output.txt into artifact directory
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME} ARGS -v > ${ARTIFACTS}/output.txt
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   COMMENT "run ${PROJECT_NAME} in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
                   VERBATIM
)
```

Within WSL using commands '*cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" $unit_tests_root*' & '*make*', CMake generates file: '*...\build\Pipeline\CMakeFiles\unit_tests.dir\build.make*', which shows:

```
...
unit_tests: CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/link.txt
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=/mnt/c/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests/build/Pipeline/CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_30) "Linking C executable unit_tests"
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --blue --bold "run unit_tests in /mnt/c/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests"
    cd /mnt/c/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests && /mnt/c/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests/build/Pipeline/unit_tests -v > /mnt/c/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests/artifacts/output.txt

# Rule to build all files generated by this target.
CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/build: unit_tests
...
```

This toolchain is working: The unit tests are executed and output is printed to output.txt.

---

Within cmd using commands '*cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" %unit_tests_root%*' & '*make*', CMake generates the same file: '*...\build\Pipeline\CMakeFiles\unit_tests.dir\build.make*', which shows:

```
...
unit_tests.exe: CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/link.txt
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir=C:\repos\project-source\tests\unit_tests\build\Pipeline\CMakeFiles --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_30) "Linking C executable unit_tests.exe"
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\unit_tests.dir\link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --blue --bold "run unit_tests in C:/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests"
    cd /d C:\repos\project-source\tests\unit_tests && C:\repos\project-source\tests\unit_tests\build\Pipeline\unit_tests.exe -v > C:/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests/artifacts/output.txt

# Rule to build all files generated by this target.
CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/build: unit_tests.exe
...
```

**Error message in console**: (line 555 corresponds to '*cd /d C:\repos\project-source\tests\unit_tests && ...*'

```
...
[100%] Linking C executable unit_tests.exe
run unit_tests in C:/repos/project-source/tests/unit_tests
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\unit_tests.dir\build.make:555: unit_tests.exe] Error 13
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'unit_tests.exe'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/unit_tests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:102: all] Error 2
...
```

**What's the problem with line 555?**

When I comment out the '*add_custom_command(...)*' within CMakeLists.txt, the unit_tests.exe builds successfully and I can execute it manually with:

```
C:\repos\project-source\tests\unit_tests>.\build\Pipeline\unit_tests.exe -v > .\artifacts\output.txt
```

Somehow the output is not the same as the output I get when build and executed within WSL, but at least it can be executed...

**Edit 1**, Additional Information: I am calling these commands (cmake, make) within a python script via subprocess.run(): I have the assumption, that this locks the files - still evaluating this...

**Edit 2 / Solution**, I found the problem: The error actually is returned by the unit_tests.exe itself as it has 13 errors (I missed the fact, that unity exits with the amount for errors). That's why make exits with errors and deletes the executable. Now I prefer calling the executable explicitly in my python script, where I also call the cmake and make commands. @Tsyvarev, sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your contribution. ;-)

Comment: "What's the problem with line 555?" - Probably, execution of this line returns non-zero value, which is treated by Make as an error. You can easily check that by running exactly the same command (`cd /d <...> && <...>\unit_tests.exe -v > <...>`) and examine its exit status.

Comment: I can't examine the status by calling the command, because the `unit_tests.exe` gets deleted after the error occurs: make[2]: *** Deleting file 'unit_tests.exe. Does Error 13 mean Access Denied?

Comment: You may temporary comment-out your `add_custom_command`, so `unit_tests.exe` will be created and you will be able to **manually** run the **exact** command used for testing.

Comment: I added the second edit or solution respectively.